# JavaScript : When function passing in the argument it is returning ```NaN```

Tags: javascript, function, parameters, arguments

here is my code problem

```
function abc(num,x,y){
 return num * x + " " + num * y;
}

abc(5,2,4); //returns 10 20

abc(5,abc(5,6,6),4) //doesn't return 30 30 20
```

I also want to know how to achieve if I call the function below (function inside the argument of the same function)-

```
abc(5,abc(abc(5,abc(5,6,6),abc(5,abc(5,6,6),4)))) // it must return something like how abc(5,abc(5,6,6),4) should return 30 30 20
```

I want when I call the function `abc(5,2,abc(5,abc(5,4,4),3))` should return all parameter every time  like `10 20 20 15` for calling the function - `abc(5,2,abc(5,abc(5,4,4),3))` if I place the same function in the function Parameter/arguments.

I tried but when I call the function inside the same function arguments like `abc(5,abc(5,6,6),4)` the `x` in the `function abc(num,x,y)` becomes `NaN` hence returns like `NaN 20` but not `30 30 20`

---

if I do like

```
 function abc(num,x,y){
if(isNaN(x)){
return x + " " + y * num ;  //now it returns 30 30 20 for abc(5,abc(5,6,6),4)
}
 return num * x + " " + num * y;
}
```

but how to do for this `abc(5,abc(abc(5,abc(5,6,6),abc(5,abc(5,6,6),4))))` to return the same way like above edited.

Comment: What's the logic behind `abc(5,abc(5,6,6),4) ` returning `30 30 20` ? Can you elaborate ?

Comment: you function abc returns a string type which you are trying to multiply it with a number which will result into NaN, trying casting it with parseInt while calling abc and it should be fine.

Comment: @LakshyaThakur question edited  ```abc(5,abc(5,6,6),4)``` returns ```30 20 20``` what i wanted to achieve but still i am on my way to get the asnwer for ```abc(5,abc(abc(5,abc(5,6,6),abc(5,abc(5,6,6),4))))```  to return the same way.

Answer (score 0):

Your function `abc(num,x,y)` returns a string, which then cannot be used arithmetically in the next function.

Answer (score 0):

Your function abc returns a string type which you are trying to multiply it with a number which will result into NaN, trying casting it with parseInt while calling abc and it should be fine.

```
function abc(num,x,y){
     return num * x + " " + num * y;
}
    
abc(5,2,4); //returns 10 20
    
abc(5,parseInt(abc(5,6,6)),4) // return "150 20"
```

Comment: ```function abc(num,x,y){
if(isNaN(x)){
return x + " " + y * num ;  //now it returns 
}
 return num * x + " " + num * y;
}```  this one does better and what i actually wanted to achieve but not for  this one i am still seaching ```abc(5,abc(abc(5,abc(5,6,6),abc(5,abc(5,6,6),4))))```

Comment: ok in the above case it would still be having parseInt every time you get return something or better wrap the return value in parseInt and it will work for the above scenario like return parseInt(num* x + " " + num * y);