# JavaScript regex returns two matches without /g flag

Tags: javascript, regex, return

Here is my code I tried many different ways to achieve but failed to do here is the expression `/((\s?)+\d{1,}(\s?)+,(\s?)+\d{1,}(\s?)+,(\s?)+\d{1,}(\s?)+)/` which should return only one match i.e. `123,24,23233` because I am not using `\g` flag. But it returns weird output i.e. `123,24,23233,123,24,23233,,,,,,` same thing two times

But why when I use `\g` flag i.e. `/((\s?)+\d{1,}(\s?)+,(\s?)+\d{1,}(\s?)+,(\s?)+\d{1,}(\s?)+)/g` , it works properly and returns `123,24,23233,123,24,23233325676`.

**My problem is I want regex to return the first match which is `123,24,23233`. but getting weird return which is `123,24,23233,123,24,23233,,,,,,`**

*Reference 1/2:*

```
  var str = "(3,(123,24,23233),(3,3,(123,24,(123,24,23233325676))))"; 
  var exp = /((\s?)+\d{1,}(\s?)+,(\s?)+\d{1,}(\s?)+,(\s?)+\d{1,}(\s?)+)/;
  var res = str.match(exp);  
  console.log(res);
```

*Reference 2/2:*

1. [JSfiddle (Without /g flag)](https://jsfiddle.net/980wpa7L/)
2. [Jsfiddle (With /g flag)](https://jsfiddle.net/no9zm8h5/)
3. [Regex](https://regex101.com/r/foVu4i/1)

Comment: These are all your capture groups.

Comment: try this `/(\s*\d{1,}\s*,\s*\d{1,}\s*,\s*\d{1,}\s*)/`

Comment: @WaseemAlmoliky wrap your expression in back-ticks (`\``)

Comment: thanks @Mr.Polywhirl. or like this `/((\s*\d+\s*)(,\s*\d+\s*){2})/`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you did not include the global flag, ***"only the first complete match and its related capturing groups [will be] returned."***

You will want to destructure the first group from your match object. The full match is the first item in the match result.

```js
const
  str = "(3,(123,24,23233),(3,3,(123,24,(123,24,23233325676))))", 
  exp = /((\s?)+\d{1,}(\s?)+,(\s?)+\d{1,}(\s?)+,(\s?)+\d{1,}(\s?)+)/,
  [fullMatch, res] = str.match(exp);  

console.log(res); // 123,24,23233
```

---

Please review [`String.prototype.match()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/match) and the [`RegExp`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp) object over at MDN.

> *if the g flag is not used, only the first complete match and its related capturing groups are returned.*

## Reference documentation

> ### Return value
>
> An `Array` whose contents **depend on** the presence or absence of the global (`g`) flag, or `null` if no matches are found.
>
> - If the `g` flag is used, all results matching the complete regular expression will be returned, but capturing groups will not.
> - if the `g` flag is not used, only the first complete match and its related capturing groups are returned. In this case, the returned item will have additional properties as described below.
>
> #### Additional properties
>
> As explained above, some results contain additional properties as described below.
>
> `groups`
>
> An object of named capturing groups whose keys are the names and values are the capturing groups or `undefined` if no named capturing groups were defined. See Groups and Ranges for more information.
>
> `index`
>
> The index of the search at which the result was found.
>
> `input`
>
> A copy of the search string.

Comment: Thanks a lot brother. if you don't mind can you look at this question as well. I need an answer. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67053701/javascript-when-function-passing-in-the-argument-it-is-returning-nan